# submitting a form with out using submit?

Tags: php

I want to submit a form without using submit button how can i do that?

Comment: You need to add more details I think, like what (action, element) should submit the form, HTML code sample. Additionally, you should take a look at jQuery (events onXXXX and ajax functionality) : see http://jquery.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do this. Check this

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: What happens when the user has JavaScript disabled? accessibility issues!

Comment: In that case you need to think of some alternative approach like using the<noscript> tags to display a button which post back the complete page, but for this your actual button which do the form submit in the background should be constructed in the <script> tag.
Or you can simpally show a message that "JS is disabled, so this page will not work"

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript. Something like

document.forms["myform"].submit();

or

document.myform.submit();

You need to set the name (1. example) or id (2. example) attribute for your form to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Through javascript you can call `form.submit()`

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's form methods to serialize the form variables and send via ajax.

http://api.jquery.com/category/forms/

You can add some javascript logic to ANY submit methods by passing a function to the form's submit event handler.

Eg.

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(){
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  return false;
});
```

Returning false blocks the form from being submitted by all other methods (including the "traditional" submit button).  You'd put your ajax code before the return statement.

or add bind the submit function to ANY dom element (image,button,etc.) 
Eg.

```
$('#my_cool_image').click(function() {
  $('#my_form').submit();
});
```

See more at http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Good Luck